# Proof that forgetful functor on groups preserves reflexive coequalizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I was looking for a proof of the fact that the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves reflexive coequalizers, but couldn't find one. Here is what I have:

---

Let $A {\rightrightarrows}^f_g B$ be a reflexive pair of groups with common section $s$.
The coequalizer in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is $A \rightrightarrows_g^f B \xrightarrow{q} B/N$ where $N$ is the normal closure of $S = \{f(x)^{-1} g(x) \mid x \in A\}$.
The coequalizer in $\mathbf{Set}$ is $A \rightrightarrows_g^f B \xrightarrow{e} B/{\sim}$ where ${\sim}$ is the equivalence relation generated by $R = \{(f(x), g(x)) \mid x \in A\}$.
To prove the claim, we need to find a set isomorphism $B/N \cong B/{\sim}$ that commutes with $e$ and $q$ appropriately.
It suffices to show that the equivalence relation $\sim_N$ induced by $N$ on $B$ is exactly equal to ${\sim}$.

First note that the subgroup generated by $S$ is already normal.
To prove this it suffices to show that the generating set is stable under conjugation.
And indeed, for any $b \in B$ we have $b^{-1} f(x)^{-1} g(x) b = (f(x) b)^{-1} g(x) b = f(x\cdot s(b))^{-1}g(x\cdot s(b)) \in S$.
We can use this to characterize congruence modulo $N$ more simply.

We show that $\sim_N$ is also generated by $R$, which concludes the proof. By definition, $y \sim_N z$ for $y, z \in B$ if and only if $y^{-1}z \in N$.
Since $N$ is the subgroup generated by $S$, we can write $y^{-1}z = s_0s_1^{-1}s_2s_3^{-1} \cdots s_n$ where $s_i \in S$.
Write $s_i = f(x_i)^{-1}g(x_i)$.
Also, $y = g(s(y))$ and $z = f(s(z))$.

Here is where I get stuck... My idea was showing that we can write something like $y \sim_N f(x_1) \sim_N g(x_1) \sim_N f(x_2) \sim_N \cdots \sim_N z$ to show that $\sim_N$ is generated by $R$.